# Why C/C++ does not defined expression evaluation order?

Tags: c++, c, expression, evaluation

As you may know C/C++ does not specified expression evaluation order. What are the reasons to left them undefined.

Comment: I am expecting some good answers. Like, for left-to-right (or other) evaluation order a compiler can generate optimized (A) assembly code (x86) block from some statements (such as function call or other) and for undefined evaluation order a compiler can generate optimized (B) assembly code (x86) block. It is also good to have some comparison (like why (B) is faster if it is) between (A) and (B).

Moreover, how good the decision was? Many optimization techniques are not normally implemented (including set of platform specific techniques)

Comment: You want example code? Try various programs in gcc! It heavily depends on the program and available optimizations. Also you answered your last question by yourself. If you fix the evaluation order, no reordering optimizations would be possible.

Comment: For some statements GCC may only generate (B) code (of my previous comment) only if GCC can able to generate optimized code for undefined expression evaluation order.

Answer (score 5):

It allows compiler optimizations.
One example would be the reordering of arithmetic instructions for the maximum usage of the ALUs or hiding memory latency with calculations.

Answer (score 0):

One of the C/C++ design goals is the efficient implementation for complilers. So the compilers are given relatively free rein in choosing the evaluation order of various subexpression within a complicated expression; this order is not constrained by operator precedence and associativity as we think. In such situation when we a modifying the same vairiable in multiple sub expression, the behaviour become undefied. An increment or decrement operation is not guaranteed to be performed immediately after giving upthe previous value and before any other part of the expression is evalauted. The only guarantee is that the update will be performed before the expression is considered finished.

**Undefined behavious means undefined and anything can happen**.

Source:C programmig FAQ by Steve Summit